# Appending to inherited method docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, docstring

I'm trying to define a subclass that only changes the `__init__` method, that change will change the behavior of some of the methods and I wanted to be able to update the docstrings accordingly. I have been trying something like this:

```py
class ParentClass:

    def __init__(self):
        """Init docstring"""
        self.x = 1

    def return_x(self):
        """Will return 1"""
        return self.x

class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 2

ChildClass.return_x.__doc__ = "Will return 2"
```

However, by doing this I change the docstring for the `return_x` method in the parent class as well:

```py
>>> x = ParentClass()
>>> help(x.return_x)
    "Will return 2 now"
>>> x = ChildClass()
>>> help(x.return_x)
    "Will return 2 now"
```

I tried other variations to this, but it either led to an error or changed the Parent Class docstring as well. Is there any simple way that I can change the child class docstring without having to redefine the method?

**Edit 1**, In response to @Anonymous12358 comment:

My intention in not needing to redefine the method is to avoid repetition of a complicated method signature and a relatively long documentation. In my real case the change to the documentation can be made by simply appending a sentence to the end of the original documentation. So I'm looking for an implementation similar to:

```py
ChildClass.return_x.__doc__ += "\n Appended sentence to the doc"
```

Comment: do you mind if the parent docstring change as well or not? It seems that they change in "tandem"

Comment: Yes, the change just has effect in the child class. Ideally just the child docstring should be changed.

Comment: I did some tests but... they share the signature and docstring so I don't if it is possible to have different docstrings. I can only update the docstring without boring extra calls

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `return_x` method in the child class with an explicit foward to the `super`, and write a docstring for the override:

```python3
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    ...
    def return_x(self):
        """Will return 2"""
        return super().return_x()
```

The subclass will still always have the same behaviour as its parent, but now has its own version of the method and therefore its own docstring.

Comment: The questions was specifically about not having to redefine the method.

Comment: @James The method will have the same implementation, so I assumed this would not count as redefining. If OP indeed meant that any form of creating a separate method object was unacceptable, then to my knowledge there is no way to do this (except with horrible black magic).

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I was concerned if that would not be adding an extra overhead from the call to the parent class method. Also, I was hoping that there is a solution in which it is explicit that the only change I'm making is to redefine the docstring.

Comment: I agree that how I posed the question your solution solves the problem. Indeed the overhead from the function call is negligible. Yet, I'm still curious if there's a solution to this that doesn't involve having to redefine the method. The reason being that in my real case, the method signature is a little bit more complicated, and the change made can be explained by appending a sentence to the original docstring. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Anonymous12358: `copy.copy` doesn't actually copy function objects - it just returns the original.